# Json to Object Deserialization

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I am receiving a json through an api and this json i want to desrialize into an object. But everytime i get all the properties as null.

Below is the json i want to serialize into an object :

```
{
"RequestReceived": "2017-05-09T12:48:16.7068095-04:00",
"ResponseSent": "2017-05-09T12:48:16.7068095-04:00",
"AfterAuth": "2017-05-09T12:48:16.7068095-04:00",
"AfterRepo": "2017-05-09T12:48:16.7068095-04:00",
"StatusCd": 0,
"ErrorDesc": "",
"NextPossibleRole": [
    {
        "NextPossibleRoleId": "40002026",
        "NextPossibleRoleLongName": "Business Strategy Consultant",
        "NextPossibleCareerLevel": "9"
    },
    {
        "NextPossibleRoleId": "40003572",
        "NextPossibleRoleLongName": "Senior Business Strategy Consultant",
        "NextPossibleCareerLevel": "9"
    },
    {
        "NextPossibleRoleId": "40006639",
        "NextPossibleRoleLongName": "Senior Strategy Consultant",
        "NextPossibleCareerLevel": "9"
    }
]
```

}

Below is the class which i have created for this json :

```
 public class NextPossibleRole
  {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty("id")]           
        public string NextPossibleRoleId { get; }
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string NextPossibleRoleLongName { get; }
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty("level")]
        public string NextPossibleCareerLevel { get; }


  }
```

Below is the code which iam using to deserialize

```
TADObject = new NextPossibleRole();
TADObject = oSerializer.Deserialize<NextPossibleRole>(result);
```

Everytime i try to look into the class through the debugger it gives me all the above properties as null.

Please help.

Comment: Your json shows that `NextPossibleRole` has a property called `NextPossibleRoleId` but you are specifying in the attribute that you should expect a property named `id`. Is your json example correct?

Comment: The json properrties in the C# class dont match the json you are serializing?

Comment: @Ctrl_Alt_Defeat that is quite clear from the post that JSON is collection of `NextPossibleRole` and not a single one - what exactly you are looking to confirm?

Comment: Also, the Json does not represent a `NextPossibleRole` object per-se. It is a Json object / dictionary which has a property named "NextPossibleRole". This property has an array of many  `NextPossibleRole` objects assigned.

Comment: @Alexei - this article is well worth reading for users like yourself https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You class doesn't match and it's only part of the json.

```
public class NextPossibleRole
{
    public string NextPossibleRoleId { get; set; }
    public string NextPossibleRoleLongName { get; set; }
    public string NextPossibleCareerLevel { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public string RequestReceived { get; set; }
    public string ResponseSent { get; set; }
    public string AfterAuth { get; set; }
    public string AfterRepo { get; set; }
    public int StatusCd { get; set; }
    public string ErrorDesc { get; set; }
    public List<NextPossibleRole> NextPossibleRole { get; set; }
}
```

Then your json deserialization code should look like

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use json2csharp to generate your C# classes.

http://json2csharp.com

I would then nane the properties in C# naming convention and use the Json property name annotation to give the correct name to the property as is in yoir json object

Answer (score 1):

Parsing the JSON string you got leads to the following class structure you have to implement:

```
public class NextPossibleRole
{
    public string NextPossibleRoleId { get; set; }
    public string NextPossibleRoleLongName { get; set; }
    public string NextPossibleCareerLevel { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string RequestReceived { get; set; }
    public string ResponseSent { get; set; }
    public string AfterAuth { get; set; }
    public string AfterRepo { get; set; }
    public int StatusCd { get; set; }
    public string ErrorDesc { get; set; }
    public List<NextPossibleRole> NextPossibleRole { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to cater every JSON name-value pair in your contract. From what you have posted it looks like you have made a sub-contract where the members you have defined include NextPossibleRoleId/LongName etc.

Your contract should handle all name-value pairs. Starting from requestReceived and finishing at NextPossibleRole. NextPossibleRole will itself be another contract as it contains three members of itself.